# Assembly Fnstenv Function

Tags: assembly

I'm new to assembly and came across this piece of code:

```
nop
fldz
fnstenv[esi]
mov eax, [esi+0xc]
```

I couldn't find a clear explanation of 'fnstenv' online, can anyone explain it in this context? What would be the value of eax after running this program?

Comment: Not sure where you looked. See section _8.1.10 Saving the x87 FPU's State with FSTENV/FNSTENV and  FSAVE/FNSAVE_ in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 1: Basic Architecture_

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov eax, [esi+0xc]
> ```

Since you are reading a full dword from the saved environment, it's only logical to conclude that you are using the 32-bit protected mode format of the `fnstenv` instruction.

This means that you'll get the *FPU Instruction Pointer Offset* which was saved at offset 12 within the state image.

The `EAX` register will hold the address of the `fldz` instruction because that was the last non-control instruction that the FPU executed.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by Sep Roland, this piece of code fills register `eax` with the memory address where the instruction `fldz` is located.
It's a hackers' trick to obtain the current instruction pointer; a valuable piece of information in [shellcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode).
Your code snippet may well be part of an [exploit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)).

Source: [Daniele Bellavista's Blog](http://danielebellavista.blogspot.nl/2014/10/ia32-shellcodes-get-eip-value.html).